# Android: JSONObject with volley response

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, android-volley

Im trying to download data from a server in the form of a JSON object, parse that object then use the data elsewhere in my app.

Ive created a class which downloads the data (confirmed with a Log.v statement)

The trouble is that i want to display the results in a RecyclerView and the List of objects that i generate after parsing the JSON response does not get generated until after the adapter method is called from my main class.

So my question is, given the code below, how can i ensure that the on response method only exits once the parseResponse method has finished. Currently i am returning the (Null) _releaseList from my requestAndPareseReleaseList method.

```
public class ParseReleaseJSON extends JSONObject {

    String _url;
    List<ReleaseInfo> _releaseList = Collections.emptyList();

    ParseReleaseJSON(String url) {
        super();
        _url = url;
    }

    public List<ReleaseInfo> requestAndParseReleaseList(Context _context){
        JsonObjectRequest jsObReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, _url, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

     @Override
      public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
          releaseList = parseResponse(response);
    }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.v("err", "nosuccess");
            }
        });
        MySingleton.getInstance(_context).addToRequestQueue(jsObReq);
        return _releaseList;
    }
    private List parseResponse(JSONObject response) {

        List<ReleaseInfo> list = new ArrayList<>();
        if(response == null || response.length() == 0){
            return list;
        }
        try {
            if(response.has("results")){
                JSONArray resultsArray = response.getJSONArray("results");
                for(int i = 0, j = 6; i < j; i++){
                    ReleaseInfo release = new ReleaseInfo();
                    JSONObject tempObj = resultsArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    release.title = tempObj.getString("title");
                    release.date = tempObj.getString("date");            
                    list.add(release);         
                }
                return list;
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to call your code out of the ui thread... and after inflate your layout  I recommend to use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: The issue is that the addToRequestQueue() method is asynchronous, which means that after executing that line, the request will start on a background thread, while the main thread continues execution and returns the empty _releaseList. You should simply update the data in your RecyclerView inside the onResponse() method.

Comment: Thanks kleinsenberg for that clear explanation. Its useful to know why its been happening. I actually tried to update my recyclerView inside the onResponse() method before posting this code but i got a runtime Exception saying that i had requested and not released a resource. However i will investigate further.

Thanks also to D-Darkcloud for the comment - I will look into calling on the UIThread